# Latex doesn't show parts of code using "listings" package

Tags: r, latex

I'm using the "listings" package to show some R code in my document.
The problem is that part of the code doesn't appear in the document.

This is the Latex code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Loading Dataset},label=lst:datasetLoading]
airportsData <- read.csv("dataset\\airports.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")
colnames(airportsData) <- c("openflightCode" , "name", "city", "country", "IATA", "ICAO", "latitude", "longitude", "altitude", "timezone", "DST", "tzdb", "type", "source")
\end{lstlisting}
```

and these are my lstsetting:

```
 \lstset{
         language=R,
         basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
         numbers=left,           
         numberstyle=\tiny,       
         numbersep=5pt,        
         tabsize=4,                 
         extendedchars=true,         
         breaklines=true,
         keywordstyle=\textbf,           
         stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily,
         showspaces=false,       
         showtabs=false,           
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framexrightmargin=5pt,
         framexbottommargin=4pt,
         showstringspaces=false          
 }
```

and this is the output in the document:

[latex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgKcX.png)

How can i solve this problem?

EDIT: I've attached an MRE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,           
    numberstyle=\tiny,       
    numbersep=5pt,        
    tabsize=4,                 
    extendedchars=true,         
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\textbf,           
    stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily,
    showspaces=false,       
    showtabs=false,           
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    showstringspaces=false
}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Loading Dataset},label=lst:datasetLoading]
    airportsData <- read.csv("dataset\\airports.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")
    colnames(airportsData) <- c("openflightCode" , "name", "city", "country", "IATA", "ICAO", "latitude", "longitude", "altitude", "timezone", "DST", "tzdb", "type", "source")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz why you need a minimal example? If you refer to the .txt file, It doesn't matter what the .txt file contains

Comment: It is terrible boring having to write all the things like a documentclass and the necessary packages before even being able to start working on your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76295961/latex-listings-doesnt-show-code-inside-single-and-double-quotation answer here, i created a new post

Comment: In the future please edit your questions to improve them instead of posting about the same problem again. Please at least clean up this post. Having the same post several times does not help this site in building a high quality library of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in `quote = "\""`. The first quote opens a string, and while your intention is for Latex to read `\"` as the string literal `"`, you need to specify this in your `lstset`. Right now, the quote following the backslash closes the aforementioned string. The next quote after this begins a new string, which continues into the next line; since you have `stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily` you are turning all strings (incuding the unintentional one) to white.

Per [the listings documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (page 24), you need to add
`morestring = [b]"` to your `lstset`.

Here is an MRE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,           
    numberstyle=\tiny,       
    numbersep=5pt,        
    tabsize=4,                 
    extendedchars=true,         
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\textbf,           
    stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily,
    showspaces=false,       
    showtabs=false,           
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=4pt,
    showstringspaces=false, 
    morestring=[b]"
}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Loading Dataset},label=lst:datasetLoading]
    airportsData <- read.csv("dataset\\airports.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")
    colnames(airportsData) <- c("openflightCode" , "name", "city", "country", "IATA", "ICAO", "latitude", "longitude", "altitude", "timezone", "DST", "tzdb", "type", "source")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I have attached the output with the included `stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily` [image: here] For verification I included the output when `stringstyle=\color{black}` in the same image.